# Light up LED on PIC10F200 uC

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, pic, led, microchip

uC: pic10f200
Programmer: PICkit 4
IDE: MPLAB X IDE v5.45

I'm learning assembly from scratch and it appears all example assembly code for Microchip's uCs has been obsoleted from MPLAB X XC8. I am struggling to get an LED to light up trying to transcribe the old syntax and commands with the new one.

The code builds without errors, however my LED is not lighting up! I measured 0V across pin 3 which is GP1 that I am using to drive the LED.

I believe it is probably the XORWF command which I copied from example code and honestly not quite sure how it works. I'm so close to getting it to work so any help is appreciated!

```
    #include "xc.inc"
    ;CONFIG 
        CONFIG CP = OFF, MCLRE = OFF, WDTE = OFF
        ORG   0x0000
    START:               ;initializing the microcontroller
        MOVLW 0xFD       ;these two lines set GP1 as an output
        TRIS  GPIO
        XORWF GPIO, F    ;this line is where we set GP1 output high to light the LED
    LOOP:
        GOTO  LOOP       ;loop forever
    END                  ;needed to end the program
```

Comment: It might be helpful to link or quote the original you were trying to translate from.  I've never used PIC, but that might help people who do spot something that got lost in translation.

Answer (score 1):

With `MOVLW 0xFD`, your W register contains 0b1111 1101. At startup, the GPIO register contains 0b0000 0000. When you XOR these two values, you get 0b1111 1101, so GP1 is still at 0V.

Replace `XORWF GPIO,F` by `BSF GPIO,1` and your LED should lit.